# What statistical test could I use to compare categories of two data sets (for enrichment) with hugely different sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, paired-data, fishers-exact-test

I have some biological variant effect prediction data. This data can be split into categories based on the biological effect each variant has. I've turned this into two data sets: One is the "full" data set that has entries for about 34000 variants; the other is a subset of this data sets for particular variants of interest (roughly 1000 times smaller at about 33 variants). I want to test whether the proportions of certain types of variants are significantly different in my selected subset from the overall data set, i.e., some sort of enrichment test for over-representation of certain categories. The data looks like this:

```
Consequence             Count(full)  Freq(full)   Count(subset)  Freq(subset) 
3_prime_UTR_variant     6145         0.1292514     4              0.11111111
5_prime_UTR_variant     5976         0.1256967     1              0.02777778
downstream_gene_variant 2072         0.04358160    3              0.08333333
intergenic_variant      8150         0.1714238     7              0.19444444
intron_variant          6129         0.1289149     1              0.02777778
missense_variant        8116         0.1707086     10             0.27777778
splice_acceptor_variant 16           0.0003365375  0              0.00000000
splice_donor_variant    6            0.0001262015  0              0.00000000
stop_gained             234          0.004921860   1              0.02777778
```

So, the numbers in the first column are much larger since the subset is contained within this full column.

I've had a few thoughts: Chi-squared test, Fisher's Exact Test and t-test. I don't think t-test is appropriate, since I'd only be comparing between the result within each category, not between categories. Chi-squared; maybe? I've tried this but I'm skeptical of the output. Fisher's Exact Test; perhaps if I can put it into a 2x2 contingency table, but I'm struggling to picture how I would do that.

The main issues I feel are that I'm basically comparing sample sizes of one (correct me if I'm wrong), and that the second data set is a subset of the first. I'm also unsure about the legitimacy of comparing frequency data using these methods. However, I really want to know whether we see an differences of representation in these selected variants and I can't think of any other reasonable ways to represent the data.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: So, I tried making contingency tables and then running a Fisher's Exact Test on each. I also made sure to exclude the selected variants from the larger list. The tables were along the lines of:

```
             All    Selected
stop_gained  233    1
Other        47278  35
```

For each type. The way I interpret this, is I am testing the association between the dataset used and the variant type. I'm still not sure this is exactly what I want to test, which is whether I see significantly more stop_gained than expected by chance in the selected set, based on the proportion in the total set. Any thoughts?

Comment: Suppose you have exact 34000 variants, you need to separate them into 2 groups: One has 33 variants that are special, and another has 33967 variants. Then compare the response variables between two groups.

Comment: (a) As in @user158565's comment, do not compare the whole with a small part.
Compare the part with the remainder, giving you two disjoint groups.

(b) I assume you want to know whether the two groups have different proportions of counts for the various 'Consequence' categories. I assume these categories are also disjoint. 

(c) You seem to have a number of specific comparisons in mind. It is not
clear how many, and how the data in the table are to be used for that. Can you give a specific example of _one_ comparison you want to make?

Comment: @BruceET So, I guess that makes sense to remove the smaller set from the big set (although, I wonder how much of an impact it would make on the larger set with the sheer magnitude of scale difference). For (b), yes, I would like to know if the relative proportions of counts are different for each category. So, for example, If we look at "stop_gained", there are only 234 such instances in the entire data set. However, there is one in the small set. This seems to me unlikely to occur just by chance (i.e., I would expect no "stop_gained" in the small set if it were just random).

Comment: You may be right about little computational impact, but it's never good to compare even a few items to themselves. In some cases it can make the difference btw a significant result and not.